# How to fetch data with many-to-many relations

Tags: mysql, sql, many-to-many

I am currently designing a database schema. Since I haven't touched SQL for a long time, so I get stuck with fetching data from two tables with many-to-many relation.

I got three tables. *Products* table stores the information of products, *Colors* table stores the hex code of colors, and *ProductColors* represents the many-to-many relation between them. (One product can have many colors, and one color can belong to many products.)

**Products**

- product_id: int PK
- product_name: varchar(255)
- brand: varchar(255)

**Colors**

- color_id: int PK
- color_hex: char(10)

**ProductColors**

- product_id: FK (reference to Products.product_id)
- color_id: FK (reference to Colors.color_id)

[image: Products Data]

[image: Colors Data]

[image: ProductColors]

Suppose I want to find all products that have the color **"#68a832"** and are from brand **"A"**. I should get "shirt-1" & "shirt-2". What SQL command do I need to execute to retrieve these data? Does it have to use JOIN or there's some method that can retrieve the data without using JOIN.

Thank you!

Comment: *Does it have to use JOIN or there's some method that can retrieve the data without using JOIN.* You may use either JOIN or WHERE EXISTS. And even WHERE IN.

Comment: please provide sample data and desired output

Comment: are you opposed to using a JOIN for some reason?

Comment: @eshirvana sorry, I have edited the problem description. thank you~

Comment: @MBeale No, I am just being curious whether JOIN is the only solution.

Comment: @黃翌軒 . . . `JOIN` is not the *only* solution.  But it is the natural solution and makes the query more readable than alternatives (which would require multiple subqueries).